# Rails nil value when saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I am trying to implement a user authentication system inside rails, this is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :id, :email, :name, :password, :created_at, :updated_at
  has_secure_password

  before_save { email.downcase! }

  validates :email, presence: true, :uniqueness => { :case_senstive => false }

  validates :name, presence: true

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Running in the console i can read the User table successfully, then when i try to create a record:

```
User.new(:name => "A", :email => "a@a.a", :password => "password")
```

running `valid` on it retrurns `true`, but when saving the record, i get error:

```
users.password may not be NULL
```

Extracting the `password` out of the `hash` works fine.

What is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you setting `:password_confirmation`?  The example in the docs suggests you need it.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Comment: i believe that the `:password_confirmation` is optional in the recent versions

Comment: no. that field is required. But if you don't need it in your form, you can set that field in controller before saving: `user.password_confirmation = user.password`

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is in `has_secure_password`. If you are using that you should have string field `:password_digest` (it's where your encrypted password will be saved). And you need delete field `:password` and your validator of presence for that too. After add `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'` .
And now that should work

```
user = User.new(:name => "A", :email => "a@a.a", 
                :password => "password", :password_confirmation => "password")
```

But better use great gem https://github.com/plataformatec/devise . It has everything you need.

**NEW ADDED**

you should have `attr_accessible` for `:password_confirmation` too and that field should be used in your form.

[more info about has_secure_password](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/826a85069627060c11baf932423702b1228dd4df/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L34)

Comment: i have `password_digest` and the `bcrypt` gem installed. I can't use devise for the project